# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' when its installed?

Tags: python

I installed requests useing `pip install requests` and it installed successfully.
But when i go to run my program it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'`? Ive tryed uninstalling it and installing it again to no luck.

Ive also done `pip list` and it says its installed

Comment: maybe try `python -m pip install requests`. Maybe you have several versions of python on your pc

Comment: Try `pip3 install requests` or `python3 -m pip install requests`

Comment: Could you briefly describe your environment? As @tushortz says, it is likely that you have several Python executables on your PC. One possibility is that you're installing `requests` for whichever Python you have stated in your PATH, but then attempt to use it elsewhere – for instance, a PyCharm-generated virtual environment with its own Python copy.

Comment: @tushortz  yea just checked i had 2 installed lol, just deleted one and now its working fine, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that you are having more than one Python installations and you have this module installed in one installation but using another for execution.

You can check the Python interpreter you are using for execution.

Run

```
pip show <module name>
```

and check the module causing issue, is in which location, this will tell you which Python installation you should use as your interpreter or else you can copy the module files manually to your current Python interpreter installation's location.

[image]